# How to scale logstash nodes?

Tags: elasticsearch, apache-kafka, logstash, elastic-stack

We have a BELK setup where a  single Logstash is currently pulling logs from "kafka" and its currently lagging by millions. How can it be scalled on logstash side? How can i add a 2nd logstash server and make them share the load?

Answer (score 2):

If you start a 2nd instance and it uses the same [group_id](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/logstash/current/plugins-inputs-kafka.html#plugins-inputs-kafka-group_id), all of the partitions will be split evenly among the 2 logstash instances.

Worth making sure your messages are being distributed evenly among all partitions (i.e. your messages are not being put into one or just a handful of partitions).

FYI you can also tune your single instance of logstash if you haven't already. In particular, the default number of [consumer threads](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/logstash/current/plugins-inputs-kafka.html#plugins-inputs-kafka-consumer_threads) is 1, which only makes since if you have 1 partition.